# What determines a minor/major version in a javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm having some doubts regarding my code version.

```
/**
* Classe que contém um único teste que executa na mesma incidência quanto o número de parâmetros definidos. <u>Teste parametrizado</u>
 *
 * @author Wanderley Drumond
 * @since 12/03/2022
 * @version 3.1.2
 */
```

Is there some conventional rule regarding that? I'd like to follow a pattern.

Comment: see [semver](https://semver.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Most Java projects mostly follow [Apache version numbering](https://apr.apache.org/versioning.html) (which looks like the same as [semver](https://semver.org/) which Bagus's suggested).

Basically, a version is MAJOR.MINOR.HOTFIX, so the version 3.2.1 has MAJOR=3, MINOR=2 and HOTFIX=1. Then (compared to the previous version):

- Increment the MAJOR version if the release contains backwards incompatible changes.
- Otherwise, increment the MINOR version if the release contains new features.
- Otherwise, increment the hotfix version. So the release only has hotfixes (security fixes, bugfixes etc).